# iOS-style on/off toggle button for NSButton?

Tags: button, uibutton, toggle, nsbutton, nssegmentedcontrol

Looking for a MacOS equivalent of the iOS on/off toggle button seen here:

[image: on/off]

Is using an `NSSegmentedControl` the best option here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mondo Switch which is part of the Cocoa Mondo Kit.
Reference URL is http://mcormier.github.com/CocoaMondoKit/

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a `NSSegmentedControl` – works out of the box and aesthetically and functionally works nicely. The only difference being that the whole area isn't clickable as a single toggle target.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions:

- [Cocoa On/Off Switch Control](https://bitbucket.org/dainkaplan/cocoa-on-off-switch-control/overview), an extension of [PRHOnOffButton](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/prhonoffbutton/wiki/Home)
- Rip the code out of [Playdar](https://github.com/mxcl/playdar.prefpane)

[image: Cocoa On/Off Switch Control Screenshot]
[image: Playdar Screenshot]